# Group by query Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two Models, cards and risks

Cards has the following columns:

```
1. id
2. weight
3. color  //There are four types of colors, green, red, yellow, blue
```

Risks has the following:

```
1. id
2. name
3. description
4. card_id
```

What I want to achieve is a count of how many risks are, grouped by colors, for example:

```
'color' => 'green'
'count' => '4'

'color' => 'blue'
'count' => '2'

'color' => 'red'
'count' => '6'
```

So far I haven't been able to make this query using Eloquent, maybe some DB::raw could help?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
Risk::select('card.name', DB::raw('count(risks.card_id)'))
->rightJoin('cards', 'card.id', '=', 'risks.card_id')
->groupBy('risks.card_id')
->get();
```